# SharePoint - Document Filtering (Tags/Metadata?)

Tags: sharepoint, tags, metadata, file-management

I'm creating a SharePoint site which will be used to dynamically store and display documents on various pages, among other things. Is the following possible?

My view is to have one central Document Library which will include all files. Files with have 'tags' or 'metadata' attached to them. On pages, i will add a document library (or similar) webpart and then call only those documents with a certain tag/metadata.

For example.

Document Library ('**Folder**') - Contains ('**Project Document.xls**' and '**Training Document.ppt**')

On '**index.html**' i will add '**Folder**' to the page, but i only want to display '**Project Document.xls**' not '**Training Document.ppt**'.

I'm aware that you can set up target audiences but that requires a lot of user management.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this sounds like something you could accomplish using a filter. The name of the file is stored as a column. Try editing the web part on that page and edit the current view. That view will be cached for that page without changing the view across the site. If you want to be able to dynamically choose the document you display then one option is to add an HTML Form web part (which contains a text box and submit button), connect it to the doc library web part and filter the name column based on the HTML Form web part.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mike. Does the filter use the file name to filter the documents? Id like the filter to show different file names/types. So id like to show all files referring to 'projecta' filtering out all other files in that document library.

Comment: Yes, if you filter it by name then it would filter it by the document name. You can also add columns to the document library, such as a category. This might help you if you wanted to be able to identify files relative to a category and then filter by that.